# $L^2$ norm estimate involving derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I recently came across the following estimate in a paper by Laptev and Weidl and I was not able to prove it myself. If $u\in H^1(\alpha,\beta)$ and $u(\beta)=0$ with $\beta>\alpha\geq 0$, then
$$\int_\alpha^\beta \lvert u(r)\rvert^2r\,dr\leq 2^{-1}(\beta-\alpha)^2\int_{\alpha}^\beta\lvert u'(r)\rvert^2r\,dr.$$
I started off by supposing that $u\in C^\infty(\alpha,\beta)$ and WLOG $u>0$. Then by Minkowski's integral inequality and Holder we have
$$ \int_\alpha^\beta \lvert u(r)\rvert^2r\,dr=\int_{\alpha}^\beta \left(\int_{r}^\beta u'(t)r^{1/2}\,dt\right)^2\,dr\leq \left(\int_{\alpha}^\beta\left(\int_{\alpha}^{t}u'(t)^2r\,dr\right)^{1/2}\,dt\right)^2$$
$$\leq \left(\int_{\alpha}^\beta\lvert u'(t)\rvert\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{t^2-\alpha^2}\,dt\right)^2\leq 2^{-1}(\beta-\alpha)\int_{\alpha}^\beta\lvert u'(t)\rvert^2(t-\alpha)(t+\alpha)\,dt$$
$$\leq 2^{-1}(\beta-\alpha)^2\int_{\alpha}^\beta\lvert u'(t)\rvert^2(2t)\,dt$$
But this is not quite the estimate that we want. Maybe I made an error here or there is an alternative estimation scheme that could work. I tried integration by parts but it didn't really go anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
\int^{\beta}_{\alpha} |u(r)|^2 r dr =& \int^{\beta}_{\alpha} \left|\int^{\beta}_r u'(\tau)\tau^\frac12 \frac{d\tau}{\tau^\frac12}  \right|^2 rdr\\
\le& \int^\beta_\alpha \left(\int^\beta_r|u'(\tau)|^2 \tau\ d\tau\right)\left(\int^{\beta}_r\frac{d\tau}{\tau} \right)\  rdr\\
=& \int^\beta_\alpha \left(\int^\beta_r|u'(\tau)|^2 \tau\ d\tau\right)\left(\log(\beta)-\log(r)\right)r\ dr\\
\le&  \left(\int^{\beta}_{\alpha} |u'(\tau)|^2\tau\ d\tau  \right)\left(\int^{\beta}_{\alpha} (\log(\beta)-\log(r))r\ dr \right)
\end{align}

By basic calculus or by drawing a picture, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(\beta)-\log(r)}{\beta-r} \le \frac{1}{r}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^\beta_{\alpha} (\log(\beta)-\log(r))r\ dr \le \int^\beta_\alpha (\beta-r)\ dr = \frac12 (\beta-\alpha)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think you computed that inside integral correctly. It should be $\int_{\alpha}^t r\, dr = \frac{1}{2}(t^2-\alpha^2)$

Comment: @MSA2016 You are absolutely right. I made a very stupid mistake. Anyway, I have fixed the issue. It should be okay now.

Comment: Wow that is insanely clever. I would not have thought to multiply and divide by $\tau^{1/2}$. Thanks.

Comment: @MSA2016 No problem. This type of tricks is quite common in the literature. With a little bit of time,  I promise this will not surprise you.